# The query with the pagenavi function does not work and the get function works

Tags: laravel, pagination

I have such a problem to create an advanced search and now, as in the search option, I will select the daily dose, i.e. it will execute conditional instructions
$ Usee-> GroupBy ("date");
It gets a message

> Blockquote`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dat' in 'group statement' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from`usees`left join`products`on`products`.`id`=`usees`.`id_products`left join`forwarding_descriptions`on`usees`.`id`=`forwarding_descriptions`.`id_usees`left join`descriptions`on`descriptions`.`id`=`forwarding_descriptions`.`id_descriptions`where`usees`.`id_users`= 38 and`products`.`id`in (160) group by`dat`)`
>
> Blockquote
>   Just as if he did not do all these selectRaws at all, but in turn if he does not have this option, the daily dose works all well and only does not work for paginate for get works and for simplepaginate also works which is wrong giving cource code.

```
public function createQuestions($bool) {
    $usee =  usee::query();
    $hour = $this->selectHourStart(Auth::User()->id);
    $usee
            ->selectRaw("products.name as name")
            ->select( DB::Raw("(DATE(IF(HOUR(usees.date) >= $hour, usees.date,Date_add(usees.date, INTERVAL - 1 DAY) )) )  AS dat "))

            ->selectRaw("hour(usees.date) as hour")
            ->selectRaw("sum(usees.portion) as por")
            ->selectRaw("day(usees.date) as day")
            ->selectRaw("month(usees.date) as month")
            ->selectRaw("year(usees.date) as year")                
            ->selectRaw("usees.portion as portion")
            ->selectRaw("usees.date as date")
            ->selectRaw("descriptions.description as description")
            ->selectRaw("descriptions.date as date_description")
            ->selectRaw("usees.id_products as product")
            ->leftjoin("products","products.id","usees.id_products")
            ->leftjoin("forwarding_descriptions","usees.id","forwarding_descriptions.id_usees")
            ->leftjoin("descriptions","descriptions.id","forwarding_descriptions.id_descriptions")

            ->where("usees.id_users",Auth::User()->id);
    if (Input::get("data1") != "") {
        $usee->where("usees.date",">=",Input::get("data1"));
    }
    if (Input::get("data2") != "") {
        $usee->where("usees.date","<=",Input::get("data2"));
    }
    if (Input::get("dose1") != "" and Input::get("day") == "") {
        $usee->where("usees.portion",">=",Input::get("dose1"));
    }
    if (Input::get("dose2") != "" and Input::get("day") == "") {
        $usee->where("usees.portion","<=",Input::get("dose2"));
    }
    if (Input::get("search") != "") {
        $usee->where("descriptions.description","like","%" . Input::get("search") . "%");
    }
    if (Input::get("inDay") != "") {
        $usee->where("descriptions.description","!=", "");
    }

    if ($bool == true) {
            $usee->whereIn("products.id",$this->id_product);
    }
```

//chodzi o to
                if (Input::get("day") != "") {

```
                $usee->groupBy("dat");
                if (Input::get("dose1") != "" ) {
                  $usee->havingRaw("sum(usees.portion) >= " . Input::get("dose1"));
                }
                if (Input::get("dose2") != "" ) {
                  $usee->havingRaw("sum(usees.portion) <= " . Input::get("dose2"));
                }
            }
            else {
                $usee->groupBy("usees.id");
            }
    $list =    $usee->orderBy(Input::get("sort"),"DESC")->paginate(200);
    //foreach ($list as $l) {
      //  print $l->name;
    //}
    return $list;

}
```

> 

Comment: I think that on your groupBy you will need to pass DB::Raw("(DATE(IF(HOUR(usees.date) >= $hour, usees.date,Date_add(usees.date, INTERVAL - 1 DAY) )) ) again, instead on "dat"

Comment: Thanks it working.

Answer (score 0):

I made and now write error

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.`date, INTERVAL - 1 DAY) )) )` order by `date` desc' at line 1 (SQL: select (DATE(IF(HOUR(usees.date) >= '5', usees.date,Date_add(usees.date, INTERVAL - 1 DAY) )) ) as dat , hour(usees.date) as hour, count(*) as dos, sum(usees.portion) as por, day(usees.date) as day, month(usees.date) as month, year(usees.date) as year, usees.portion as portion, usees.date as date, descriptions.description as description, descriptions.date as date_description, usees.id_products as product, products.name as name from `usees` left join `products` on `products`.`id` = `usees`.`id_products` left join `forwarding_descriptions` on `usees`.`id` = `forwarding_descriptions`.`id_usees` left join `descriptions` on `descriptions`.`id` = `forwarding_descriptions`.`id_descriptions` where `usees`.`id_users` = 38 and `products`.`id` in (160) group by `(DATE(IF(HOUR(usees`.`date) >= '5', usees`.`date,Date_add(usees`.`date, INTERVAL - 1 DAY) )) )` order by `date` desc)